# Time-varying constant input in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I'm trying to generate a constant input inside my Simulink model, but I don't know how to make it time-varying. Say in `0-10`, it should output `5`, then for `10-20` the output should be `0`, then after `20`, it should output `10`.

I was trying `repeating sequence` generator module, but that was doing linear increase on intervals; I need step or sudden increase at exact points.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a time varying constant an oxymoron?

Use the [Signal Builder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/signalbuilder.html) Block, or define the signal in MATLAB and use a [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) Block.